# how to use ASP.NET FileUpload in 3-tired webApp?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, web

I have a 3-tired webApp including :
- BLL (Business Logic Layer)
- DAL (Data Access Layer)
- WebSite
The first two are `Class Library` and the last is a website as the name indicates.
The question is how to use ASP.Net `fileUpload` in this 3-tired webApp in order to write a logically separated code with the highest possible running time speed. As a matter of fact I don`t know where (BLL or webSite?) should I write code for fileUpload validation , reducing image size sent by users, and ...

EDIT:Code What i Tried

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs     e)   
{  \\get and check extension ,check file size    
    string path = Server.MapPath(".");         
    FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(path+     "\\"+FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);  \\reduce image size and save  again      
   }
```

Comment: will you send code which you tried?

Comment: @Ajay : `protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs     e)   {  \\get and check extension ,check file size             string path = Server.MapPath(".");             FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(path+     "\\"+FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);  \\reduce image size and save  again         }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question it would appear its not an SOA application, and the logical application layers are split and running on the same servers and as class library's probably within the same app domain. This simplifies the need to worry about transferring data around, as you can just pass a reference to a steam of data between the layers.

Depending on what you're doing with the file once uploaded and how many uploads happen will impact on the best way to achieve this.

The simple option is to

1. receive the file on the website and send the input to a stream
2. send the stream to the BL to validate (file type, size, create thumbnail etc)
3. BL send the stream to DL (if you're writing it to a database)

If you're not going to write to a database, then the BL or Facade could then write to disk or send elsewhere.

If you're planning on having lots of files uploaded and you're going to be processing them (i.e. resizing, creating thumbnails etc) then looking at a good queue system might be beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

On website project, in your UI's back end side you should write the code to get path of files or if you are converting image into byte so prepare byte array or path string where you want to save.

after that it will call your business side class that contains the method to store the data

and finally business layer class call the data access layer to store data to database.

that way your code should write to gain three layer architecture.